# MIPS assembly delete matching array elements

Tags: assembly, linked-list, mips

I have built a doubly linked list of numbers, and then sorted the elements with a bubble sort using MIPS assembly language. What I'm having trouble with is how to write a delete function that will fine duplicate values, and then alter the pointers of the elements before and after the duplicated value so it is not referenced. Each element contains a pointer to the element before it and after it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `d` points to the node to be deleted, then in C:

```
d->prev->next = d->next;
d->next->prev = d->prev;
d->next = d->prev = 0;
```

This is the general case.  If the list is not circular, you will need special cases for the head and tail, but these are not hard.  Since you didn't provide your code, you'll have to take care of the MIPS version.